# Trying to POST through POSTMAN json data with foreign key

Tags: java, json, spring, jpa, postman

I have two entities, myAppUser and Absences, and I'm trying to create an Absence related to his 'owner', an user. The absences is posted well, but the relation between the absence and the user never happens.

```
@Entity
public class Absence {

    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)   
    @Id
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private int id;
    @Nullable
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private Date dateMissing; 

    @Nullable
    @JsonProperty(access = Access.READ_WRITE)
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private String comment; 

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @JoinColumn (name="student_id", nullable = false)
    private MyAppUser userStudent;
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class MyAppUser {

    //@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY) 
    @Id
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String id;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String firstName;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    private String lastName;
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private String email;
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private char gender;
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private int age;
    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)
    private String portrait;
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    @ManyToOne
    private Seat seat;

    @JsonView(View.SummaryWithOthers.class)    
    @ManyToOne
    private Absence userAbsence;

    @ManyToOne (fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn (name="rol_id")
    private Role role;

    private String password;
    private boolean enabled;
    private Date lastLogin;

    @OneToMany (targetEntity = Absence.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List <Absence> absences = new ArrayList <Absence>();
    @OneToMany (targetEntity = Course.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JsonView(View.Summary.class)
    public List <Course> courses = new ArrayList <Course>();
    @OneToMany (targetEntity = UserExercice.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List <UserExercice> userExercices = new ArrayList <UserExercice>();
    @OneToMany (targetEntity = Emails.class, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List <Emails> emails = new ArrayList <Emails>();

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="myAppUser")
    @JsonIgnore
    Set<UserIteration> userIterations;
```

MyAppUser Repository

```
public interface MyAppUserRepository extends JpaRepository<MyAppUser, String>{

    public ArrayList<MyAppUser> findByFirstName(String firstName);
    public ArrayList<MyAppUser> findByLastName(String lastName);
    public List<MyAppUser> findByGender(char gender);
    public ArrayList<MyAppUser> findByRoleId(int roleId);

    Optional <MyAppUser> findOneById(String id );

    MyAppUser findUserById(String id );
}
```

Controller

```
    //Create absence by student id
    @PostMapping("/api/students/absences")
    public Absence createAbsence(@RequestBody Absence absence, MyAppUser userStudent) {
        return absencesService.createAbsence(absence, userStudent);
    }
```

Service

```
    public Absence createAbsence(Absence absence, MyAppUser userStudent) {

        String studentId = userStudent.getId(); //absence.getUserStudent().getId();
        Absence absenceCreated = new Absence();
        userStudent = myAppUserRepository.findUserById(studentId);

        absenceCreated.setComment(absence.getComment());
        absenceCreated.setDateMissing(absence.getDateMissing());
        absenceCreated.setUserStudent(userStudent);

        myAbsenceRepository.save(absenceCreated);
        return absenceCreated;
    }
```

JSON in POSTMAN

```
{
    "userStudent":{
            "student_id":"58a55a41-04cc-4007-a322-e7bb969e626b"
        },
    "dateMissing": "1574541388697",
    "comment": "prueba"
}
```

And it's returning this:

```
{
    "id": 485,
    "dateMissing": 1574541388697,
    "comment": "medic issue",
    "userStudent": null
}
```

I don't know if I'm typing the JSON wrong or if my service is going something wrong but I'm really noob in Spring and I don't get it... Just need to access to the user repository and get one by its String ID, How can I?

Thank yall!!^^

Comment: Should it not be `return absencesService.createAbsence(absence, absense.getUserStudent())`? Your controller is getting the `Absense` from the Body, but has no context for the UserStudent object (hence null).

Comment: good thinking, but it doesn't works... :( maybe i'm typing something wrong in json? I'm pretty lost @kendavidson

Comment: I also tried doing absencesService.createAbsence(absence, absence.getUserStudent().getId()) to catch the ID i'm passing through json, but doesn't work either... Thanks anyway @kendavidson !

Comment: When you debug the service are the values correct?

Comment: I'm really bad debugging with spring, but I see that student ID isn't catched and it's setted to null directly @kendavidson

Comment: It worked with your initial idea but i had to change the Json body to { userStudent:{id: ... }}. Thanks!

Comment: Ah. Ya. I didn't even notice the name of your field. Sorry, I assumed that part was good. Glad it's fixed.

Comment: @Jaykooh, can you share you final code, I have the same issue but I do not see the whole line of your solution